# Real-time overview shows numbers. Audience overview – not

Tags: google-analytics

While I see some numbers on the "Real-Time overview" page, I don't see the pageviews / sessions data in "Audience overview" on my website. I'm having a hard times understanding why.

The website is: https://everyelixirvideo.page/. It's a single-page website with no custom javascript. This is the current tracking code:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-33420511-4"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-33420511-4');
  gtag('config', 'UA-33420511-4', {'page_path': "/"});
</script>
```

**What am I missing?**

Here are the screenshot of "Real-Time overview" and "Audience overview" pages:

- good:

  [image: real-time overview]
- not good:

  [image: audience overview]

Comment: How long did you wait? There is a processing latency of up to 24 hours (so essentially you have a reporting gap between realtime and the time the data takes to show up in the permanent reports).

Comment: @EikePierstorff that I didn't know, thanks! The site's up for like 3 or 4 days now. Initially there was only a default `gtag.js` code, suggested by GA.The final line `gtag('config', 'UA-33420511-4', {'page_path': "/"})`, was only added a couple of hours ago.

Comment: @EikePierstorff do you think `gtag('config', 'UA-33420511-4', {'page_path': "/"})` line should be kept though or it is safe to remove it? From the GA debugger for Chrome, I can see the event being sent twice now https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE1ul.png

Comment: You need only one of those lines. The second gtag line always sets the page path to "/". I cannot image that is want you want.